# How to make this piece of code look better

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js, reducers

This is one of my redux reducers and I feel it looks very ugly. Is it possible to improve it?

The goal that I want to achieve is very simple:

If I already have this item in my current state, increase the quantity by 1,
otherwise add this item to state.

```
function globalReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART: {
      let { item } = action;
      if (state.getIn(['sideCart', 'orderItems', item.id])) {
        item.quantity = state.getIn(['sideCart', 'orderItems', item.id]).get('quantity') + 1;
      } else {
        item.quantity = 1;
      }
      item = fromJS(item);
      const newState = state.setIn(['sideCart', 'orderItems', item.get('id')], item);
      return newState;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The state should look like this:

```
sideCart: {
    orderItems: {
      1: {
        id: 'orderItems-1',
        name: 'AI Brown\'s BBQ Fillet of Beef with Brown Mushroom Brandy Sauce',
        quantity: 10,
        price: 12,
        subitems: ['0', '1', '2'],
        instruction: 'No rosemary for beef',
      },
      2: {
        id: 'orderItems-2',
        name: 'AI Brown\'s BBQ Fillet',
        quantity: 10,
        price: 14,
        subitems: ['0', '1', '2'],
        instruction: 'No rosemary for beef',
      },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would enhance it syntactically:

```
const reduceCart = (state, action) => {
  let { item } = action;
  const stateIn = state.getIn(['sideCart', 'orderItems', item.id]);
  item.quantity = stateIn 
      ? stateIn + 1
      : 1; 
  item = fromJS(item);
  return state.setIn(['sideCart', 'orderItems', item.get('id')], item);
};

const globalReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART: return reduceCart(state, action);
    default: return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for helping @luboskranc If getIn and setIn is side effect, how will you handle this case?

Comment: `state.setIn` is from Immutable.js and returns a new state, leaving the previous state unmodified. So no side effects.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same complexity when using immutable.js to handle deeply nested objects. I have made a lightweight immutable helper: [ImmutableAssign](https://github.com/engineforce/ImmutableAssign) that allows you to continue working with plain JS objects, which will simplify your operations.

In the following example, it expects **state** and **action** to be plain JS objects, and it will return you a **new state** as plain JS object:

```js
function globalReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TO_CART: return addCart(state, action);
        default: return state;
    }
}

function addCart(state, action) {               
    let { item } = action;

    return iassign(state, 
        function(state, context) {                    
            return state.sideCart.orderItems[context.item.id] 
        },
        function(selectedItem) { 
            item.quantity = selectedItem.quantity ? selectedItem.quantity + 1 : 1;                
            return item;
        },            
        { item: item });
}


// The first parameter is a function that return the 
// property you need to modify in your state.
// This function must be **pure function**, therefore "item" 
// need to be passed in via the context parameter. 
// 
// The second parameter is a function that modify selected 
// part of your state, it doesn't need to be pure, therefore 
// you can access "item" directly
//
// The third parameter is the context used in the first 
// function (pure function)
```